# Menu does not appear unless in debugging mode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu

I just freshly installed Wordpress and CiviCRM on my GoDaddy hosting. Installation appears to have worked fine.

When I go into CiviCRM however, the CiviCRM menu bar does not appear at the top but does appear at the bottom of the page half-obscured as text links in sort of a drop down fashion.

When I enable debugging mode, everything works fine...

Any ideas? Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

[image: without debugging on]

Comment: I encountered the same issue on a fresh install of **CiviCRM 5.18.3** on **WordPress 5.2.4**. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript for the menu bar is served up from two different places, depending on your debug setting. So good job tracking down that difference.

- in debug mode it is served from a dynamic script which is slower, but doesn't rely on the file system.
- in regular mode, the script is cached in a file. If you're CiviCRM files directory is incorrectly configured, or inaccessible due to permission problems on your server, then it will not load. FYI all Angular-based pages (e.g. CiviMail) rely on this file caching as well, so they too will be broken.

I recommend you double-check your system settings for file directories and resource URLs, and also ensure those directories are publicly readable on your server.